# I need scrollbar to start in the content (not in the heading) - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i am creating a dialog box in jquery mobile with some data. The scrollbar is stratingfrom the heading instead of just the content. Is it possible to start the scrollbar only for content and not the heading. Here is my code:
dialog.html

```
<body >


<div id="Dialog" style="width: 400px; min-height: 200px; max-height: 250px; overflow: auto;"> 

    <div data-role="header" class="mHeader" data-close-btn="right">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
            <h3 style="display: inline-block; width: 130px; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; font-size: 16px; color: #FF0000; float: left; margin-left: 48px; margin-top: 9px;">Names</h3>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 130px; float: left; margin-left: 250px; margin-top: -35px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; color: #5089B5; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;"> Reports</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 2px 15px 15px 15px;">
        <div  style="width: 300px; padding-left: 27px; ">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">
                <div  style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 6px 6px 12px; color: #222222"> ABC</div>

                </li>
              <li data-role="list-divider" data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 6px 6px 12px; color: #222222; background: #fafafa;">ABC

              </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">ABC

              </li>
              <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">ABC

              </li>     
            </ul>    
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">
                <div  style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 6px 6px 12px; color: #222222"> ABC</div>

                </li>
              <li data-role="list-divider" data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 6px 6px 12px; color: #222222; background: #fafafa;">ABC

              </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">ABC

              </li>
              <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">ABC

              </li>     
            </ul>    
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">
                <div  style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 6px 6px 12px; color: #222222"> ABC</div>

                </li>
              <li data-role="list-divider" data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" style="font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 6px 6px 12px; color: #222222; background: #fafafa;">ABC

              </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">ABC

              </li>
              <li data-role="list-divider"  data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">ABC

              </li>     
            </ul>    



        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: For providing code you need to use 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the max-height and overflow on the content div instead of the dialog div:

```
<div id="Dialog" style="width: 400px; ">
    <div data-role="header" class="mHeader" data-close-btn="right">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
             <h3 style="display: inline-block; width: 130px; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; font-size: 16px; color: #FF0000; float: left; margin-left: 48px; margin-top: 9px;">Names</h3>

            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 130px; float: left; margin-left: 250px; margin-top: -35px; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; color: #5089B5; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">Reports</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 2px 15px 15px 15px; min-height: 150px; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="width: 300px; padding-left: 27px; ">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
               ...
```

For mobile, you will also want to add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; as well as overflow: auto.

As your code is out of context, it is hard to know your exact situation. You may need to use javascript to calculate desired height...

**UPDATE**: Adrien Be has jolted me out of my laziness :)

You should also avoid inline CSS as it is very hard to maintain and you often end up repeating the same rules in many places instead of just applying a class. Instead, set up classes in a CSS file and apply those classes to your elements.

For example, instead of:

```
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 2px 15px 15px 15px; min-height: 150px; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
```

Try

```
<div data-role="content" class="scrollableContent">
```

Then create a scrollableContent class in your CSS file:

```
.scrollableContent {
    padding: 2px 15px 15px 15px; 
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: inline styling! :( come on, I'm sure you can also show him a better way to do this

Comment: Thank you @AdrienBe! I have overcome my laziness and updated the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, I just wanted to let you know that I don't use inline style. I just used it to show the code.